# Why is there a crease in my mesh when I enable subdivision surface?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology, subdivision-surface

I have a dinosaur mesh (more or less thanks to [this](https://youtu.be/GICkjUOlPPg)).  Around the 11:55 mark or so, he shift+d's the toe from one side of the foot to the other.  However, I observe that whenever I turn on subdivision surface, there is a strange crease in the mesh.

[image]

What did I do wrong to cause this crease?  What can I do to get rid of it?

Thanks alot!  Blend is [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=50824).

Comment: Do you have any double vertices or a crease setting?

Comment: I just hit "remove doubles" and I don't appear to have any, no.  I can double check the creases... and no.

Comment: can you add your blend file to your question? Grab the URL of the question
Go to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/
Select the blend file
Add the url of the question
Grab the url that results
Go back to the question and edit it

Add the new url to the bottom of the post

Comment: See if there's a face inside of the mesh like this https://youtu.be/ZtSh4Yedafg?t=1946

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have inner faces, delete them and it will work:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, what could I do, out of curiosity, to create such faces by mistake?

Comment: you might have pressed f by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Either there are multiple vertex points in the same spot, or those edges are marked sharp, and should appear blue in edit mode