# How to get rid of these hard edges after enabling mirror and subdivision modifer?

Tags: edges, topology

I've started modeling a character in Blender.

The goal is to model half of the character on one side of the origin and use the mirror modifier to duplicate the mesh on the other side of the x-axis. I also want to enable smooth shading and add a subdivision modifier so that I can get an idea of what the character will look like later when I apply them.

However, somewhere along the line, I must have done something incorrectly because now I have seams showing up in certain sections of the mesh:

[image]

Things I have already tried:

- *Mesh →Clean Up →Merge by Distance*
- Ensuring that bevel weight and crease are set to $0$ for the edges
- Screaming into the void

Sadly, none of this helped. What can I do to make the seams disappear?

Here's a copy of the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124231/why-is-there-a-crease-in-my-mesh-when-i-enable-subdivision-surface?rq=1 you look like you have interior faces along your centerline

Comment: @Sazerac That was exactly the problem — thanks!